# Get object from NSMutableDictionary and display it in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios4, nsmutabledictionary

**SETUP**

I have an NSMutableDictionary of NSMutableDictionaries. I create a dictionary of searched for terms, and now i want to display them. I used a method (below) to copy the items that contained the search term into another dictionary. I know that it is copying because i can print the dictionary and see the results. Also the correct amount of rows are displayed, but not data in them. I have included the method that copies the dictionary, and what the dictionary looks likes in the original array and what it looks like in the new array.

**PROBLEM**

My understanding of pulling items out of NSDictionaires is not correct. i have read multiple places and i know i want to use objectforkey. But i cant figure out how to get the dictionaries out of the main dictionary and display them.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}    
if (searching) {


 //ATTEMPT ONE
 //        NSDictionary *searchEmp = [copyListOfItems objectForKey:[copyListOfItems allkeys]];    
//        cell.textLabel.text = [[searchEmp objectForKey:kFULLNAME_TAG] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];               

//ATTEMPT TWO     
    NSString *name = [[copyListOfItems allKeys] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    NSString *value = [copyListOfItems objectForKey:path];

    cell.textLabel.text = [copyListOfItems objectForKey:value];




}else{

     NSDictionary *employee = [[self.orderedSections valueForKey:[[[self.orderedSections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = [employee objectForKey:kFULLNAME_TAG]; 
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
return cell;
```

}

This is the method i used to copy from one NSMutableDictionary to another

```
for (NSDictionary *emp in employeeData)
{
    NSString *empName = [emp objectForKey:kFULLNAME_TAG]; 
    NSRange titleResultsRange = [empName rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (titleResultsRange.length > 0){
        NSLog(@"search result ---> %@" ,emp);
        [copyListOfItems setValue:emp forKey:empName];
    }

}
```

This is the NSMutableDictionary before i copy it into the "copyListofItems"

```
2 012-02-27 17:24:44.399 USSContacts[14514:10d03] search result ---> {
0 = JO;
1 = "Zary Joon";
10 = "N/A";
11 = "N/A";
2 = Joon;
3 = Zary;
4 = "N/A";
5 = "N/A";
6 = "N/A";
7 = "zjoon@usa.com";
8 = "N/A";
9 = "N/A";
BUID = "N/A";
Department = "N/A";
EmployeeId = JONZ;
Extension = "N/A";
FirstName = Zary;
FullName = "Zachary Joon";
LastName = Joon;
Mobile = "N/A";
Shift = "N/A";
Supervisor = "N/A";
Title = "N/A";
email = "zjoon@usa.com";
```

}

The dictionary that i am trying to display in the UITableView looks like this. It is a copy of the above.

```
<CFBasicHash 0x5c6aa10 [0x1175400]>{type = mutable dict, count = 1,

2 : <CFString 0x5c7cf20 [0x1175400]>{contents = "Zary Joon"} = <CFBasicHash  0x5c7d0a0 [0x1175400]>{type = mutable dict, count = 24,
0 : <CFString 0x7058790 [0x1175400]>{contents = "Shift"} = <CFString 0x7059970 [0x1175400]>{contents = "N/A"}
1 : <CFString 0x7054390 [0x1175400]>{contents = "Mobile"} = <CFString 0x7059970 [0x1175400]>{contents = "N/A"}
2 : <CFString 0x70543c0 [0x1175400]>{contents = "Title"} = <CFString 0x7059970 [0x1175400]>{contents = "N/A"}
 4 : <CFString 0x7058ed0 [0x1175400]>{contents = "10"} = <CFString 0x7059970 [0x1175400]>{contents = "N/A"}
6 : <CFString 0x7054330 [0x1175400]>{contents = "Supervisor"} = <CFString 0x7059970 [0x1175400]>{contents = "N/A"}
8 : <CFString 0x7058100 [0x1175400]>{contents = "FirstName"} = <CFString 0x5c7d2a0 [0x1175400]>{contents = "Zary"}
9 : <CFString 0x7058f80 [0x1175400]>{contents = "11"} = <CFString 0x7059970 [0x1175400]>{contents = "N/A"}
13 : <CFString 0x7051a70 [0x1175400]>{contents = "0"} = <CFString 0x5c7c100 [0x117500]>{contents = "J"}
14 : <CFString 0x7054370 [0x1175400]>{contents = "email"} = <CFString 0x5c7d2c0 [0x1175400]>{contents = "zjo@usa.com"}
15 : <CFString 0x7059ba0 [0x1175400]>{contents = "BUID"} = <CFString 0x7059970 [0x1175400]>{contents = "N/A"}
16 : <CFString 0x7058120 [0x1175400]>{contents = "1"} = <CFString 0x5c7cf20 [0x1175400]>{contents = "Zary Joon"}
19 : <CFString 0x7058c40 [0x1175400]>{contents = "2"} = <CFString 0x7063630 [0x1175400]>{contents = "Joon"}
22 : <CFString 0x7059b60 [0x1175400]>{contents = "3"} = <CFString 0x5c7d2a0 [0x1175400]>{contents = "Zary"}
23 : <CFString 0x7059bc0 [0x1175400]>{contents = "Department"} = <CFString 0x7059970 [0x1175400]>{contents = "N/A"}
25 : <CFString 0x7059960 [0x1175400]>{contents = "4"} = <CFString 0x7059970 [0x1175400]>{contents = "N/A"
26 : <CFString 0x7058770 [0x1175400]>{contents = "LastName"} = <CFString 0x7063630 [0x1175400]>{contents = "Joon"}
28 : <CFString 0x70527b0 [0x1175400]>{contents = "5"} = <CFString 0x7059970 [0x1175400]>{contents = "N/A"}
30 : <CFString 0x7058750 [0x1175400]>{contents = "FullName"} = <CFString 0x5c7cf20 [0x1175400]>{contents = "Zary Joon"}
31 : <CFString 0x70527c0 [0x1175400]>{contents = "6"} = <CFString 0x7059970 [0x1175400]>{contents = "N/A"}
34 : <CFString 0x70527f0 [0x1175400]>{contents = "7"} = <CFString 0x5c7d2c0 [0x1175400]>{contents = "zjoon@usa.com"}
36 : <CFString 0x70543a0 [0x1175400]>{contents = "EmployeeId"} = <CFString 0x5c7c100 [0x1175400]>{contents = "J"}
37 : <CFString 0x70563a0 [0x1175400]>{contents = "8"} = <CFString 0x7059970 [0x1175400]>{contents = "N/A"}
38 : <CFString 0x70580e0 [0x1175400]>{contents = "Extension"} = <CFString 0x7059970 [0x1175400]>{contents = "N/A"}
40 : <CFString 0x70563c0 [0x1175400]>{contents = "9"} = <CFString 0x7059970     [0x1175400]>{contents = "N/A"}
}
```

Cany anyone explain why it has all the additional information after the copy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track.  To use your master `NSDictionary` as a data source for your table view you need to turn it into an array, which you can do by calling `allKeys`.  This gives you an array of all the keys for the items in your master dictionary.  Get the item at the correct index and then use that as the key to extract an item from your master dictionary.

The item you extract is itself a dictionary, so you can then use `objectForKey:` to pull out whichever value(s) you want to display in the table cell.

```
NSString *name = [[copyListOfItems allKeys] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *employeeDict = [copyListOfItems objectForKey:name];

cell.textLabel.text = [employeeDict objectForKey:@"FullName"];
```

Comment: i think you may have answered a few of my questions, THanks a TON by the way. That finally makes sense! thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

The order of `[copyListOfItems allKeys]` is not guaranteed to be the same every time, but more importantly, don't worry about the extra information you see. Concrete subclasses (i.e., of CFString instead of NSString) are opaque to you; you don't need to worry that it appears to have more information.

I think you may want use something like

```
NSString *value = [copyListOfItems objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long) indexPath.row]];
```

That way at least your key is the number, which is what I'm assuming 0 through 11 are. You'll have to find a different way to get at your Department, Fullname (and so on) other fields though.

Comment: I have read some places that there is a way to alphabetize the keys in that same way you got the list...are you familiar with what im talking about?

Comment: Yes - you want `[myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:arrayOfSortDescriptors]`. There's plenty of examples out there in the series of tubes :)